# What is a Dropbox API (v2) Union Tag?

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox-api

While starting to develop a Dropbox app using the Python SDK, I'm tripping conceptually over what [the AccessLevel documentation calls a union tag](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.sharing.AccessLevel). (The concept extends beyond the AccessLevel class, but this seems like as good an example as any.)

I'm trying to understand why the `_tag` attribute basically appears to be intended for internal use only. Why, if I want to know if a user has editor, owner, or viewer permission—-and it can only be one of those--I seem to be supposed to call the `is_owner()`, `is_editor()`, and `is_viewer()` methods until I get a `True` response.

What am I missing? Why wouldn't it be a good idea to just access the `_tag` attribute and go my merry way?

Comment: I am flabbergasted seeing how poorly Dropbox has designed their APIs. Their SDKs suck. Better go with their HTTP APIs (it sucks too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API docs define `.tag` as:

> The .tag field in an object identifies the subtype of a struct or selected member of a union.

[Tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) appears to be a generic concept rather than Dropbox-specific one:

> In computer science, a tagged union ... is a data structure used to hold a value that could take on several different, but fixed, types

Wikipedia clarifies this applicability further:

> Only one of the types can be in use at any one time, and a tag field explicitly indicates which one is in use. This is critical in defining recursive datatypes ... where it is necessary to distinguish multi-node subtrees and leaves.

A good example in case of Dropbox API endpoint is `list_folder` where return can be either file or folder, i.e. `.tag` can take value of `file` or `folder`.

I believe this can be valuable for strongly typed code where returned files/folders are parsed into classes.