# What is Union and Struct in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api

I am working on a project that utilizes Dropbox API. I have been reading Dropbox API documentation and they have some over-complicated terms.

Can anyone help me understand what is Union and Struct in Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

[The Dropbox API spec](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-api-spec) is written using [the Stone interface description language](https://github.com/dropbox/stone/).

It does use a number of different types of objects, such as unions and structs. These aren't specific to Dropbox, so you can find information about them online, such as at the following links:

- [Wikipedia page for Unions in computer
  science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)
- [Wikipedia page
  for Structs in computer
  science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science))

You don't necessarily need a firm understanding of these computer science concepts to use [the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) though. There's [a Getting Started guide here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started).

We recommend using one of [the official SDKs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation), if possible, as they do most of the work for you.

Comment: I've looked through the getting started guide and SDK documents. It is not an easy to work with API. It is way too much to even write team info to an output file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49370075/6037143 - Apparently I am not the only one confused as to why I need to call `is_*` until I get a True response. Why can't I simply access the tag.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that I can utilize SDKs and do not need to worry about those `Computer Science` concepts, but the matter of the fact is that Dropbox APIs are not easy to work with. I've tried Python SDK (poor documentation).

There are way too many steps involved getting as simple as team info.

```
dbx = dbx.DropboxTeam('TOKEN')
team_info = dbx.team_get_info()
policies = team_info.policies
emm_state = policies.emm_state
office_addin = policies.office_addin
sharing = policies.sharing
folder_join_policy = sharing.shared_folder_join_policy
folder_member_policy = sharing.shared_folder_join_policy
link_create_policy = sharing.shared_link_create_policy

#Now call each is_* method on each class (office_addin, emm_state, folder_join_policy, folder_member_policy, link_create_policy) to check which options are enabled.
#This is really an overkill for something as simple as getting team info unless I am wrong.
#I would rather use the HTTP APIs, but then the info is buried deep within those nested `.tag` doors.
```

`team_get_info` is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later but this is for anyone else stumbling across this and was not able to find an answer.

I was having the same issue of not understanding what the Dropbox API meant by `union`. I am creating a backend using NodeJS that can do the basic CRUD functionality and this includes uploading an image, updating an image and removing an image from Dropbox.

I am using the the [/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) endpoint that supports uploading and updating. For updating it states that the `mode` `UploadArg` is a union so the update `mode` needs to be a union. After some time, I was able to figure the format out to be:

```
mode: {
  '.tag': 'update',
  'update': revisionID
}
```

Where in my case the revisionID is a variable that holds the id associated with the already uploaded image. The `.tag` attribute is the name of the desired union name and the `update` attribute is the additional supplied data.

The DropboxAPI Docs are still unclear as to how to properly do a union but this is what I was able to learn based on my project.